# How to Implement pagging

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am fetching data from MS app Insights . now I want to know that How paging can be implemented if there is lots of records fetching from query and all are not getting fetched in single query? I want paging in query.
I am using app insights rest api 
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart

Comment: are you using the app insights api for the query？and where do you want to implement the paging, in the query itself or after the query?

Comment: i am using app insights rest api and want paging in query

Comment: If the answer is acceptable, please help mark it as answer. And if more questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do paging in the query.

Here is a workaround you can take a try:

For example, if you want to fetch 100 datas each time, you can use $top and $skip to mimic the paging function.

In your first query, fetch the first 100 data:

```
get /v1/apps/{app-id}/events/$all?$top=100
```

Then in the 2nd query, fetch the 101-200 data:

```
get /v1/apps/{app-id}/events/$all?$top=100&$skip=100
```

in the 3rd query, fetch the 201-300 data:

```
get /v1/apps/{app-id}/events/$all?$top=100&$skip=200
```

Please also let me know if you have more questions.